# Magento Patch SUPEE 10975 can´t be applied successfully

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, patch

I can´t manage to apply the PATCH 10975 to my Magento 1.9.1.0 CE installation.

I´ve already tried to apply the PATCH after changing the config.xml to its original content, unfortunately with the same result.

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-10975_CE_v1.9.1.1_v1-2018-11-27-09-18-02.sh 
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Group/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Newsletter/Template/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/BlockController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/SitemapController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/BackupController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Observer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Model/Zend.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Image/Rest/Admin/V1.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 28.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 428 (offset 3 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 452 (offset 3 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.6.1.2-1.6.0.6.1.3.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer/Address.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/sql/payment_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1.1-1.6.0.0.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/Block/Send.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/files.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Wishlist.csv
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.1.min.map
```

What do I have to do to successfully apply the patch? Do I have to edit the Patch file or the config.xml?

Comment: Did you apply previous patches yet?

Comment: Yes a lot. The installation is about 4 years old and I have applied every necessary patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem: after editing the property `Mage_Core / version` (file: app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml) from "1.6.0.6" to "1.6.0.6.1.2", the patch could be applied successfully.

Comment: how did you know to edit this property? I am having a similar problem; in my case, there appears to be a problem in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: update: I was able to find my issue in page.xml; I had changed a line and needed to change it back. details here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269791/patch-supee-10975-cant-be-installed-successfully/269927#269927